# Extern and Linker Error

Tags: c++, linker, namespaces, extern

Why do variables need to be externed at declaration in header file and then declared again in the corresponding cpp file to:

a. Prevent Link error

```
    ex. header 1.h-
    namespace forglobal { 
    extern int x;
    }

     source 1.cpp- 
    namespace forglobal{
    int x=6;
    }

    source 2.cpp- 
    #include "1.h"
    cout<<x; //6
```

b. Use in different cpp files, can't I just use the namespace like I call a function ex.

```
    header -1.h
    namespace forglobal {
    int x
    }

    source -1.cpp {
    namespace forglobal {
    void change() {
    x=5;
    }
    }
    }

    source -2.cpp 
    #include "1.h"
    forglobal::change();
    cout<<forglobal::x<<'\n'; //5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any namespace-level variable declaration which isn't declared `extern` is also a definition. That is, if you have header with a non-`extern` variable declaration which is included in more then one translation unit linked into a program, you get multiple definitions. To prevent that, you mark the variable declaration in the header as `extern` and omit the `extern` where the definition is located.

Of course, using global variables is generally a Bad Idea in the first place but that's a different discussion.

Comment: strictly speaking, a namespace variable is not a global variable. But they all initialized automatically.

Answer (score 1):

This question is related to one fundamental concept in C++ which is One Definition Rule (ODR).
As Dietmar Kühl said, without "extern", you have multiple definitions of the same variable which will violate ODR.

However, in C++ you can have as many declarations as possible. Basically declaration introduces a name into scope and definition allocates some memory for a variable.

Please refer to the book by Bjarne Stroutstrup, "The C++ Programming language".

Answer (score 0):

In the second case, you are allocating space for the variable x in two places, so the linker wouldn't know how to access the variable.  In the former, only one place is allocated, so there is no confusion.

Comment: Do you mean when I declare x in the header and then initialize it in the source file?

Comment: I think you need to understand what a declaration is and what a definition is.